# How do I override user agent styles while using React JS and Styled-Css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome, next.js

I want to remove default padding given by user agent in chrome.
I'm using React with NextJs server.

I have tried giving padding and margin 0 in styled css but not working.

Comment: Please add some CSS and HTML code to show what you've done. Maybe a screenshot to help visualize the problem.

Comment: @ArashMotamedi `html,
  body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

In your index.css you  need to add

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```